# How to calculate the effect size in a 3 by 3 crossover design study?

Tags: mixed-model, effect-size, crossover-study

How does one proceed when one want to calculate effect sizes for a 3 by 3 crossover design, in which individuals only have one observation in each period (i.e. no repeated measurement setting)?

I would be very grateful if someone could lead me in the right direction for solving this.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by "setting of a 3 by 3 crossover design", could you share an example of the data and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have found litterature covering the case of a 2 by 2 crossover trail: Madeyski, L., Kitchenham, B. Effect sizes and their variance for AB/BA crossover design studies. Empir Software Eng 23, 1982–2017 (2018). https://doi.org/10.1007/s10664-017-9574-5 but not for the case 3 by 3 crossover trail. the setting is similar to what is in the paper, but with 3 treatments and 3 periods.

Comment: Are you the same as the poster? Same screen name ... then Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find 
information on how to do this in the **My Account** 
section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
[edit] & comment on your own question.